# Temporary disable EditText

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, focusable

I want `EditText` to temporarily not gain foucs.

Scenario is : I have two EditTexts. Whenever any EditText's text is changed, I want another EditText to not to respond to user clicks until another predefined event occurs.

To achieve that I tried this :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    registerBroadcastReceivers();
}

// Register BroadcastReceivers
private void registerBroadcastReceivers() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Registering broadcast receivers.");

    // Google response receiver
    googleResponseReceiver = new GoogleAPIResponseReceiver();
    IntentFilter googleResponseIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            RS_GoogleApiIntentService.ACTION_RECEIVED_GOOGLE_RESPONSE);
    googleResponseIntentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            googleResponseReceiver, googleResponseIntentFilter);
}

editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        // Set EditText non-focusable
        MyActivity.this.editText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    }
});

.
.
. 
// Somewhere in one function I call below function to start an IntentService.
.
.
. 

// Call Google API with given URL
private void CallGoogleApiWithUrl(String url, int requestId) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RS_GoogleApiIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra(RS_GoogleApiIntentService.EXTRA_URL_STRING, url);
    intent.putExtra(RS_GoogleApiIntentService.EXTRA_GOOGLE_API_REQUEST_ID,
            requestId);
    startService(intent);
}

// Broadcast receiver for Google API response
public class GoogleAPIResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Enabling EditText works up to this point.

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Stops working now onwards.

    }
}

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        // Set EditText focusable
        MyActivity.this.editText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

**Layout :**

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/from_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/from_location_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:imeActionLabel="Done"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/use_current_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:onClick="useCurrentLocation"
        android:text="@string/use_current"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/swap_button_description"
    android:onClick="swapLocations"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/swap" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/to_location"
    style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:hint="@string/to_location_hint"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:imeActionLabel="Done"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/departuretime_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/departure_date_hint"
        android:inputType="datetime" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/departuretime_time"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/departure_time_hint"
        android:inputType="datetime" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pick_match_create_trip"
    style="@style/big_centered_button_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:onClick="pickMatchesButtonClicked"
    android:text="@string/pick_your_matches" />

<TextView
    style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text="@string/current_location_textlabel"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/current_location_text"
    style="@style/create_trip_activity_components_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/places_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00FFFF"
    android:background="@color/white" >
</ListView>
```

EditText never gains focus again. Disabling focus works but enabling it again does not. I also tried using `editText2.setEnabled();` method. It did not work, too.

Comment: Please show declaration of editText1 and editText2 ...

Comment: you dont want the focus or you dont want the edittext to be visible

Comment: Just pointing out that calling `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)` after `setFocusable(false)` is redundant. Also, `setFocusable(true)` is not required if you are calling `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`.

Comment: are u able to do focusable false onEditTextChanged.if so then i think u can try focusable true by using handler with onPostDelayed method with a delay of 2000ms.i have used this on some similar situation

Answer (score 8):

Its really Simple my friend.
You can try something like below:

```
   editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        // Set EditText non-focusable
        editText2.setEnable(false);
        editText2.setClickable(false);


    }
});

.
.  // some work
.

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        // Set EditText focusable
                editText2.setEnable(true);
        editText2.setClickable(true);
}
```

Just update your code something like above and try. that will surly works. if not then let me know, i will help you.

Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: I tried it. Problem is once I disable it, it is not getting enabled again.

Comment: Then maybe the problem in somewhere else in your cod, do you wand to show us more of it, like the XML file?

Comment: @felixd Added xml file. The thing is if I put code of enabling EditText in some methods it works. To make it clear, first I make EditText disabled then call an IntentService and return results back to activity. To listen to IntentService's result I have broadcast receiver in my activity. So if I put code to enable EditText in broadcast receiver's `onReceive` or in any other method after broadcast receiver in app flow, this does not work.

Comment: @Akash sound like a bad wiring problem or a code block that is never reached ... please add your entire block of code including the intent request and broadcast receiver because it seems that your problem lies there.

Answer (score 2):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    editText2.setEnable(false);
    editText2.setClickable(false);
  }
}, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
editText2.clearFocus();
```

Comment: It will make first focusable object to gain focus. This is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You set `editText2.requestFocus();` when ever you want to focus on `EditText`.

Comment: I want EditText to gain focus only on user touch. Again I don't want to add onClickListener just for this purpose.

Comment: It gives false once I set false.

Answer (score 1):

write it in manifest file of activity, It defocus the edittext by creation activity at first time. and re gain the focus by touching on Edit text

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use the following code and manipulate accordingly by java.

```
`<EditText ...
    android:clickable="false" 
    android:cursorVisible="false" 
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
 </EditText>'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: <EditText ...
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</EditText>